# compare two arrays with css-properties to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to combine two arrays with css-properties to one new. The new values should overwrite old values if there was already this style defined.

The first array contains the old styles (it comes from css-classes)

```
oldcss[0]='background-image: url(\"https://www.example.com/oldfile.jpg\")';
...
```

The second array contains the new styles )it comes from css-inlinestyle)

```
newcss[0]='background-image: url(\"https://www.example.com/newfile.jpg\")';
...
```

For the tested styles (border, font, color etc.) this function works fine. This function is a part of a loop through all elements which have inline-style-properties.

```
...
const resultObj = [...oldcss, ...newcss].reduce((a, str) => {
      const [key, val] = str.split(/: ?/);
      a[key] = val;
      return a;   }, {});
finalCSS['perfix-'+$(checkEl[i]).attr('id')]=Object.entries(resultObj).map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`);
...
```

In case of the background-image property, this function failed.

I receive: `background-image: url("https;}`
instead of the wanted `background-image: url("https://www.example.com/newfile.jpg");}`

What do I have to change, so that it also works with in this case?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the `?`, since it will match between 0 and 1 of the preceding token.

So your regex should look like this: `str.split(/: /);`

Comment: it seems that it will work now, with out the ? I hope under the other conditions it will work too...thanks a lot for the moment!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you generate the key/value pair. Instead of simple split, which splits at every colon I would suggest running it through a regex:

```
const [full, key, value] = /^([^:]*):(.*)$/.exec(str)
```

Comment: ok, i want to trie what should be "full"? Could you give me a sample based on my code?

Comment: Full is here just for array destructuring, you won't need to use it at all - it's the whole matched string which is your original string from how the regex was written. @Greg